# Acer E5-574G Laptop touchpad not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: touchpad, laptop, acer

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 (64Bit) in my Laptop Acer Aspire E 15 E5-574G.
Unfortunately, touchpad is not working.

I searched for a good resource in the internet, but i couldn't find it.

If some has any information please share with me.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Please do not post outputs as images. You can copy text from terminal and post it as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this touchpad is supported by kernel 4.2.

You can install it by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

P.S. Why do you install Ubuntu 14.04.3, when 14.04.4 has been released with new hardware support? Kernel 4.2 is already there.

Comment: I updated the kernel. It works find.  Thank you.